# Error in ConfusionMatrix : `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I've conducting a tree model with R caret. I'm now trying to generate a confusion matrix and keep getting the following error:

Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

```
intrain<-createDataPartition(y=df$share, p=0.7, list=FALSE) 
train<-df[intrain, ]
test<-df[-intrain, ]

partymod<-ctree(share~., data=train)

partypred<-predict(partymod, test)
confusionMatrix(partypred, test$share)
```

I cant figure out what the problem is.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as its making me cracked!!

Comment: I think you need to set both the `levels` of the 'share' column same in both datasets.  i.e. `lvs <- union(levels(train$share), test$share)); test$share <- factor(test$share, levels = lvs); train$share <- factor(train$share, levels = lvs)`  a reproducible example would have been helpful though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Confusion Matrix : the data and reference factors must have the same number of levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002013/error-in-confusion-matrix-the-data-and-reference-factors-must-have-the-same-nu)